# Can PrestoDB be used in a production environment with 100's of Queries per minute?

Tags: presto, bigdata

I've been investigating ways to query multiple databases on different environments to provide aggregated data to a user front end.

All of my reading and research has shown that PrestoDB seems to be perfect for big data analysis. Even the example of Facebook using it seems limited to employee purposes only

What I would like to know is if anyone has successfully deployed it in a production environment where hundreds if not thousands of queries per minute have been asked of it?

Comment: At least as of 3 years ago, Netflix was a big user: http://techblog.netflix.com/2014/10/using-presto-in-our-big-data-platform.html. I'm gonna go with "it'll work if you set it up correctly".

Comment: Thanks warren. I'd read that before but I had missed their blog post on their architectural implementation.

Comment: that took me about 10 seconds to Google. Questions worded like this are not very good for a Q&A type site.

Comment: Hi warren. I have been Googling. I know it's not a great question and I shall endeavour to abide by the guidelines more. The problem is it's more of an design and implementation problem which is very subjective and you're right, it isn't great for this forum. I did actually delete and then undelete my question in desperation. Thank you for taking the time to respond. I appreciate it.

Comment: there are ways to ask a similar question that could be good :: include requirements, ask for best practices, explain your setup and ask for improvements, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Hi we are [Treasure Data](http://www.treasuredata.com/). We deployed Presto in production environment over 100000 queries / day with multi tenancy. The detailed stats are here. Please take a look if you are interested.

http://www.slideshare.net/taroleo/introduction-to-presto-at-treasure-data

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your user latency requirements. If you want the users at that volume to drill around in the graphics at near speed of thought (sub second) you're going to need a more complicated architecture than just presto. If you want to run that volume of adhoc data analyst SQL queries, it can handle it but you're going to spend a good deal on memory. Lastly, do you have the data really to need that powerful of a tool (10s-100s of billions of rows just for starters).

Query volume, user latency, adhoc nature of queries, data volume, and price footprint software/hardware need to all be taken into account at a minimum. Silver bullet solutions still do not exist at the data layer.